# Modifying the value returned by Redis RMap get() does not update the object in the map

Tags: redis

My code looks like this:

```
private RMap<String, PojoA> stringToPojoAMap;

private void updateMapEntry(String k, int id) {
    PojoA pojoA = stringToPojoAMap.get(k);
    pojoA.setId(id);
}
```

I expected the object instance in stringToPojoAMap to be updated, but only the local pojoA is updated.

This achieves what I want:

```
private void updateMapEntry(String k, int id) {
    PojoA pojoA = stringToPojoAMap.get(k);
    pojoA.setId(id);
    stringToPojoAMap.put(k, pojoA);
}
```

But should the put be necessary?

Updated a value returned by  Redis RMap get().
Expected

- map instance updated.

Actual

- map instance not updated